# How to "integrate" non-.net developers into a .net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio

I'm working on an Asp.net MVC + WebApi application that's using Azure (SQL, Storage) in the back and Angular in the front. Locally I'm running MS SQL and Azure Storage Emulator. But I desperately need some extra development brains because there's just too much work to do.

I've got a good client-side developer that will be able to help me on the Angular part of the app as well as on LESS files. So pretty much the client-side only.

The problem is that he's never used Visual Studio and doesn't intend to start doing so just for this project. He's used to client-side tools, smart editors like Sublime and similar and client automation services like Grunt or Gulp that could replace Web Essentials auto compilation of LESS files.

But there'll always be the problems of *.csproj files (they'd likely mess it up with manual edits if at all), app compilation (although that would be possible with some batch files), manage NuGet packages, database upgrades etc. It just seems too complicated without Visual Studio's automation.

**So how can you sufficiently work on a .net project without Visual Studio (or WebMatrix)?** and still be able to:

- add new/remove/rename files in the project
- add/remove/upgrade NuGet packages
- compile the app as other devs may've changed backend to support something new on the client
- else?

Who has done it, which tools should be used and how painful is it?

> **Note**: I'm not asking about software recommendations even though may read that way. I'm mostly interested in your experience and whether I should *force* that developer to go hands on with Visual Studio or not...

Comment: Wouldn't be better in [Programmers.SE]?

Comment: I'm not sure. Hence asking here?

Comment: You can use version control and a build server.

Comment: He can't. He's going to have to put on his big boy panties and learn a new ide (the horror!).

Comment: @Patrick: This developer is located elsewhere so this *build server* is most practically be setup on his own machine? I'm using private github repo.

Comment: @SonerGönül this is a bad fit for Programmers, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487 Recommended reading: [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)

Comment: Your developer should be able to use one of the free editions of VS. Additionally VisualStudioOnline (TFS in the cloud) is free for up to 5 users, and you can connect it to a GitHub repo. Once he's used VS he won't want to use anything else.

Comment: @slugster: I have licenses for full MSDN. So VS is not a problem. At all. It would likely still be better to use VS Premium for the sake of code analysis and plugin integrations. I'm not sure about latest Express versions, but these were lacking in older versions. Haven't used VS online, but I highly doubt that it has the editing capabilities like intellisense etc... But something I should consider.

Comment: "VSOnline" encompasses what was formerly known as TFS Online (ie its hosted for you, full on build servers, source control, project management, everything). I wasn't suggesting using an online VS editor - yuck!! Anyway, IOW - force him to use VS. He'll pick up the essentials pretty quick then he'll never look back, especially when its integrated into the colab tools like TFS.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Well, the build server should be setup somewhere. When you push to your gitrepo the build server gets a notification and performs a build with those changes. It doesn't matter where it's set up, but usually you have it on a server somewhere. There's a tutorial for setting up TeamCity with building web sites for instance; http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/09/automated-site-deployments-with-teamcity-deployment-projects-amp-svn

Comment: You might want to take a look at ASP.NET MVC6 (vNext). It uses easier to edit project files and supports different tools for managing client side packages. Unfortunately it's still pretty immature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to say that it isn't possible to work on a Visual Studio project without Visual Studio, but I'm definitely going to say that it isn't at all feasible.

If you are building a Microsoft MVC system within Visual Studio, then you have made that system dependent on Visual Studio.  The 'Solution' and 'Project' files are dependent on Visual Studio.  Even though they are technically XML files that can be manually manipulated, it's just not feasible to go that route.

If your developer has the resources and capabilities of installing/using Visual Studio, that's the route that s/he needs to go.  The fact that s/he has no prior experience working within Visual Studio, to me, isn't a good excuse.

Comment: It's not an exuse per se. It's just something they're not considering due to lack of VS use.

Comment: But TBH Visual Studio is nothing particular to learn. It's an editor. If you use additional gems or not is just your choice and willingness to learn. I suppose I'll try convincing him into VS. Better for all.

Comment: I agree.  Visual Studio should not be *that* complicated to learn.  You can even come up with some basic documentation for him to refer to for doing some basic things within Visual Studio that applies specifically to his use so he doesn't fumble around too much.

Answer (score 1):

IMO :-

- You should force the developer to use VS because in the end it is
  just a tool to use, with lot helpful(needed) features.
- The porting of Project would required hell of a effort and Skills, So
  in the end you will `waste most development time` in it than it would
  take the developer to get familiar with VS.
- This would be good for developer to learn and expand his
  knowledge-base about IDEs, If he is thinking that it would be hard or
  not interested to learn new stuff. Then I think you got the wrong guy
  :)

Comment: +1 *Force* as in *gun to head* as in *offer he can't refuse* as in *either your signature or your brain on the paper*? ;)